# How to safely move packages in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, package, refactoring

When I want to move a package, say `org.company.project.numbers` to `org.company.project.data` resulting in `org.company.project.data.numbers`, I use <kbd>Refactor</kbd> -> <kbd>Rename</kbd>/<kbd>Move</kbd>.

However, I want to move the entire Maven structure and make the **test** packages to copy the structure.

Example, I want to refactor the following structure:

```
src
 - main
   - java
     - org.company.project.numbers
        - Class01.java
        - Class02.java 
 - test
   - java
     - org.company.project.numbers
        - Class01Test.java
        - Class02Test.java
```

Into:

```
src
 - main
   - java
     - org.company.project.data.numbers
        - One.java
        - Two.java 
 - test
   - java
     - org.company.project.data.numbers
        - OneTest.java
        - TwoTest.java
```

Briefly the following changes in both **main** and **test**:

- Move `org.company.project.numbers` to `org.company.project.data.numbers` in **main** and **test**.
- Rename `Class01` to `One` in **main**.
- Rename `Class01Test` to `OneTest` in **test**.
- Treat the rest of classes equally.

How to safely move/rename packages and classes not only in the **main** folder but also make **test** to copy the very same structure? Using <kbd>Refactor</kbd> is not reliable since it only changes the dependencies but not the structure.

Comment: The thing is, the testing code isn't really formally dependent on the source code, at least not from a compilation point of view.  I would just move everything separately, but +1 to your question.

Comment: To rename packages you can select corresponding packages in both src and test by ctrl-clicking and then right click and select Refactor->Move... You get 3 options in the dialog but the first is probably what you should choose, at least it worked fine when I tested it. No idea about renaming classes though.